# Visual Studio becomes laggy and freezes with too much parallel loops

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, loops, parallel.foreach

We found a very strange issue in the Visual Studio.

If you put more than 6 or maybe more parallel loops into each other, the Visual Studio becomes very laggy.

If you click into the loop, and try to scroll, or try to click outside of the loops, then click into the loop again, the VS freezes for 5-10 secs.
With simple loops this problem never occurs, so we think the problem is that, in the case of parallel loops we have Actions, and maybe that kills the IDE.

We have tested this both with VS2012 and VS2013 and it's the same.

Here is my example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> _list = new List<string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_list, element1 =>
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(_list, element2 =>
                        {
                            Parallel.ForEach(_list, element3 =>
                                {
                                    Parallel.ForEach(_list, element4 =>
                                        {
                                            Parallel.ForEach(_list, element5 =>
                                                {
                                                    Parallel.ForEach(_list, element6 =>
                                                    {
                                                        Parallel.ForEach(_list, element7 =>
                                                        {

                                                        });
                                                    });
                                                });
                                        });
                                });
                        });
                });
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody had similar problems, and know a solution, please answer!

Comment: I guess that the complete system has problems than.

Comment: Seems like a bug (or 'limit' maybe) - you should probably just file a report at Microsoft.Connect and see what comes out. With 5 loops it doesn't act up?

Comment: Yes, if you use only 5 or less, there is no lag, the IDE is response as usual.

Comment: Are you sure this is only visual studio? Seems to me spinning so many threads would cause your whole OS to be slow and laggy

Comment: I'm not starting the program. Just type this code to the editor, than the IDE becomes laggy.

Comment: Do you have all extensions disabled? Most of the time they are the cause of a problem

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov what threads?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys We tried it with VS 2012 Express which has no extensions, and had the same problem. :(

Comment: @Aron i thought he was executing the program

Comment: @ZoltánBarna ah ok, then you should file a bug report. My suspicion is that it is intellisense that has a problem with the lambdas

Comment: i'm coding from an i5-3470 and with VS2013 (and some extension installed, even Xamarin) i have less than half-second freeze! Curious bug!

Comment: Yes, half second freeze, but every time you type a new character, or doing something, so it's really hard to work :) .

But if you have a more complex code (not as simple as my example), this lag time increases to 20-30 seconds :( .

Comment: I see it.  Nothing we can do about it, you can file a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com.  Or contact Microsoft Support if you can't wait.  Don't expect any miracles, this isn't very likely to be easy to fix.  Otherwise a strong hint that you are doing it wrong, nobody writes code like this, it causes a crazy explosion of threads at runtime that isn't unlikely to deadlock due to threadpool exhaustion.

Comment: You're not saying you are actually *using* code like this, so that the delay is effectively bothering you? In case you are, I'd say the code needs some serious reviews

Comment: Of course it's not usual to put a lot of loops into each other, but I was just curious why it occurs. This is a bug in the Visual Studio so  I will report this as you suggested!

By the way, if you try this code (for example put 10000 elements to the _list variable) in the Process manager you can see there is no thread exploison, according to these articles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/06/9903475.aspx .

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a visual studio bug